# Object Oriented programming in python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying my hands at some exercises, came to this one :

Create a class called ShoppingCart.

Create a constructor that takes no arguments and sets the total attribute to zero, and initializes an empty dict attribute named items.

Create a method add_item that requires item_name, quantity and price arguments. This method should add the cost of the added items to the current value of total. It should also add an entry to the items dict such that the key is the item_name and the value is the quantity of the item.

Create a method remove_item that requires similar arguments as add_item. It should remove items that have been added to the shopping cart and are not required. This method should deduct the cost of the removed items from the current total and also update the items dict accordingly.

If the quantity of an item to be removed exceeds the current quantity of that item in the cart, assume that all entries of that item are to be removed.

Create a method checkout that takes in cash_paid and returns the value of balance from the payment. If cash_paid is not enough to cover the total, return "Cash paid not enough".

Create a class called Shop that has a constructor which takes no arguments and initializes an attribute called quantity at 100.

Make sure Shop inherits from ShoppingCart.

In the Shop class, override the remove_item method, such that calling Shop's remove_item with no arguments decrements quantity by one.

Wrote this (see below) and ran it through the tests (See below), it passed all the tests, but when trying to submit it on the platform which i'm taking the exercise, it returned this error >>>> KeyError('Mango',), what could be the cause of this? and how can i solve it? if it asses all the tests, doesn't that mean the code is good to go ? i'm stuck

THE CODE

```
class ShoppingCart(object):

def __init__(self):
self.total = 0
self.items = {}

def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
self.total += (quantity * price)
self.items = {item_name : quantity}

def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
self.total -= (quantity * price)
if quantity >= self.items[item_name]:
    del self.items[item_name]
self.items[item_name] -= quantity

def checkout(self, cash_paid):
balance = 0
if cash_paid < self.total:
  return "Cash paid not enough"
balance = cash_paid - self.total
return balance


class Shop(ShoppingCart):

def __init__(self):
ShoppingCart.__init__(self)
self.quantity = 100

def remove_item(self):
self.quantity -=1
```

THE TEST

```
import unittest

class ShoppingCartTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
self.cart = ShoppingCart()
self.shop = Shop()

def test_cart_property_initialization(self):
self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 0, msg='Initial value of total not correct')
self.assertIsInstance(self.cart.items, dict, msg='Items is not a dictionary')

def test_add_item(self):
self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)

self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 30, msg='Cart total not correct after adding items')
self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 3, msg='Quantity of items not correct after adding item')

def test_remove_item(self):
self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
self.cart.remove_item('Mango', 2, 10)

self.assertEqual(self.cart.total, 10, msg='Cart total not correct after removing item')
self.assertEqual(self.cart.items['Mango'], 1, msg='Quantity of items not correct after removing item')

def test_checkout_returns_correct_balance(self):
self.cart.add_item('Mango', 3, 10)
self.cart.add_item('Orange', 16, 10)

self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(265), 75, msg='Balance of checkout not correct')
self.assertEqual(self.cart.checkout(25), 'Cash paid not enough', msg='Balance of checkout not correct')

def test_shop_is_instance_of_shopping_cart(self):
self.assertTrue(isinstance(self.shop, ShoppingCart), msg='Shop is not a subclass of ShoppingCart')

def test_shop_remove_item_method(self):
for i in range(15):
  self.shop.remove_item()

self.assertEqual(self.shop.quantity, 85)
```

Comment: Hint: write a test that adds mangos and oranges to the cart. Then check whether both of those are still in `self.cart.items`.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's way more code and explanation than needed for the issue. Also, the indentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of add_item is incorrect.

```
def add_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
    self.total += (quantity * price)
    self.items = {item_name : quantity}
```

This line:

```
    self.items = {item_name : quantity}
```

should be:

```
    self.items[item_name] = self.items.get(item_name, 0) + quantity
```

Also in remove_item you permit one to remove more quantity than there is, I could add items and then remove them and I could get free fruit:

```
def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
    self.total -= (quantity * price)
    if quantity >= self.items[item_name]:
        del self.items[item_name]
    self.items[item_name] -= quantity
```

Should be something like this:

```
def remove_item(self, item_name, quantity, price):
    if quantity >= self.items[item_name]:
        self.total -= (self.items[item_name] * price)
        del self.items[item_name]
    else:
        self.total -= (quantity * price)
        self.items[item_name] -= quantity
```

Comment: @roganjosh sorry about that, in a bid to make sure you understand the entire problem, i overloaded it. apologies

Comment: D the remove_item was the problem, thank you . What you you did is useful and the glory of it not in vain.